# Set a json objects values from an array in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have an Array of JSON objects in PostgreSQL inside data.json, That looks like this

```
[
  { "10" : [1,2,3,4,5] },
  { "8" : [5,4,3,1,2] },
  { "11" : [1,3,5,4,2] }
]
```

The data is taken from a select statement

```
 SELECT

 ARRAY((SELECT json_build_object(station_id,
   ARRAY((SELECT 

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(prodtakt_takt)
FROM psproductivity.prodtakt 
WHERE prodtakt_start::date = generate_series.shipping_day_sort::date
AND station_id = prodtakt_station_id
),0)
   FROM generate_series)) ) FROM psproductivity.station WHERE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(prodtakt_takt),0) FROM psproductivity.prodtakt WHERE station_id = prodtakt_station_id) > 0 
    )) AS json, ...
```

Where generate_series is just a series of dates.

Now I need to that and turn it into this format of a JSON object

```
{
  "x" : "x",
  "jsondata" : {
    "10" : [1,2,3,4,5]
    "8" : [5,4,3,1,2]
    "11" : [1,3,5,4,2]
  }
}
```

the software I am working on uses c3.js to process data into graphs so I have to change this format. I am thinking that I need to start with something like

```
json_build_object( 'jsondata',( SELECT FROM json_each(unnest(data.json)) ) )
```

But I can think of no route with that logic. Adding the x into the JSON object is easy. I am confident I can do that part if I can just reorganize the array

Comment: Object keys can't be strings, so that's `"10" : [1,2,3,4,5]`? And what exactly is `data.json`? A file? A column in a table?

Comment: @Schwern yes they are strings I will fix that. data.json is a record returned from a select statement Ill add that statement to the question as well

Comment: Thanks. It's a little hard to follow your query, but I think you want `json_object_agg(station_d, array(...))`. It works like other aggregate functions. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html You should also use jsonb rather than json. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: @Schwern Thank you a ton if you post that as the answer I can confirm it. The problem is a bit tricky to describe, It's hard for me to grasp so its hard to explain.